# Emacs - startup log messages are missing

Tags: elisp, emacs24

I have put some log messages in .emacs (emacs config file) like this,

```
(message "welcome to emacs")
```

I expected to see these messages in scratch buffer after emacs bootup, but it is not there. How can i add log to emacs boot code to understand it better & Where are those logs written to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These messages are written to the `*Messages*` buffer.  Apart from the usual ways of switching buffers, you can open this buffer by typing `C-h e`, or by clicking in the echo area.

Answer (score 2):

`(message "Foo")` will write "Foo" to the `*Messages*` buffer, not to scratch. The scratch buffer is intended for evaluating pieces of Emacs Lisp code mainly. The message will also briefly appear in the minibuffer (until overwritten), so if your welcome message is the last piece of elisp in your .emacs, you should see "welcome to emacs" appear in the minibuffer, too.